# How to get height of lines in TextView

Tags: java, android

Hi I am coding line numbers for a code editor.
The problem is the numbers in my line numbers isn't alligned to the code editor. The code editor have taller lines than my line mumbers even though they have the same text size.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you want. pls read faq http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.
For some reason EditTexts has padding at the top which makes it taller than the line numbers which is a TextView. The solution was to make the line numbers an EditText with android:editable set to false in xml.